# Using FullCalendar with Spring Boot, how do I persist an event?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use fullCalendar in a Java Spring Boot web application.
I cant seem to figure out how to get the request working that makes my event persist in my DB.

Here's my handler mapping for my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/event")
public void addEvent(@RequestBody Event event) {
    eventRepository.save(event);
}
```

My fullCalendar script:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        dateClick: function(info) {
          if(info.view.type==="dayGridMonth"){
            this.changeView("timeGridDay",info.dateStr);
          }
          else if(info.view.type === 'timeGridDay'){
            let newEvent = calendar.addEvent({
              title : 'test1',
              start: info.date,
              end: info.date,
              description : "test4"
            });
            $.post({
              url: "/event",
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json",
              data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newEvent)),
            });
            console.log(info.date);
        }
        },

        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev, next, today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events : {
          url : '/allevents',
          type: 'GET',
          error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching!');
          }
        }
      });

      calendar.render();
    });

  </script>
```

My event entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
public class Event {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "event_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "event_generator", sequenceName = "event_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime start;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime end;



    public Event() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(LocalDateTime start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(LocalDateTime end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Event [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", description=" + description + ", start=" + start
                + ", end=" + end + "]";
    }
}
```

I either get 403 or 400 as a return.

Comment: A [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) is quite different than a [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/status/400). You should solve the security issue first.

Comment: Try also changing `data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newEvent))` to `data: JSON.stringify(newEvent)`, because 1) It's redundant to parse something you just stringified, you simply end up back where you started, and 2) In order to transmit the data over the wire, you need it as a string in JSON format - that's what JSON.stringify does.